# python escpos Network printer does not support magicencode

Tags: python-3.x, escpos

I want to print  german characters on the receipt through the printer which is connected to my network, but the network printer does not support magicencode or any other encoding, which helps me in printing "ä"
on the receipt

Comment: Could you mention which version of the library you are using?

Comment: This article may be helpful.[Magic encoding broken on second call of the same script #272](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos/issues/272)

Comment: I am using 2.2.0

Comment: In the first place, it seems that python-escpos v2.2.0 does not have a magicencode function? [Esc/Pos -- python-escpos 2.2.0 documentation](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/v2.2.0/api/escpos.html) If it could be used for that purpose, it would probably be the [charcode()](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/v2.2.0/api/escpos.html#escpos.escpos.Escpos.charcode) method.